# ContentPlaceHolder no se adapta al contenido de página de contenido

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Cual puede ser el problema??, revise el ContentPlaceHolder y no veo el error, no veo porque queda así, con ese tamaño estático...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso lo estas viendo en el diseñador del VS o en el browser ? si ejecutas la pagina lo isualizas correctamente?

Comment: En el diseñador y si lo ejecuto se visualiza bien...

Comment: Lo imagine, no uses el diseñador del VS, hace mucho deje de usarlo, define el html y diseña visualizando directo en el browser. Es mas en asp.net mvc ni siquiera existe un diseñador, usa el browser

Comment: Gracias por el consejo Leandro